# Displaying Hasse diagram (directed edges in graph pointing upwards)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization, sets

I use the following code to display a Hasse diagram of a graph.

```
   g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 3}, 
   VertexLabels -> Thread[{1, 2, 3, 4} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}],
   VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, ImageSize -> {240, 240}];
SetProperty[g, 
  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
     Placed[{Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], Red], 
       Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexLabels], Blue]}, {Before, 
       After}]}];
SetProperty[g, 
 VertexCoordinates -> ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]@ GraphEmbedding[g]]
```

The result is a the following diagram:

[image]

Some arrows are displayed downward. They should point upward as is the case for Hasse diagrams. Can you suggest a fix?

Comment: `LayeredGraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 3}, Bottom, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[{1, 2, 3, 4} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}], 
 VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, ImageSize -> {240, 240}]`?

Comment: or `LayeredGraphPlot[g, Bottom]`?

Comment: Try `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Bottom}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate issues here:

1. How to get Mathematica to choose the root properly?
2. How to flip the plot so arrow point up?

The default layout for trees is `"LayeredEmbedding"`. This layout ignores edge directions. This is why it does not select `1` as the root. You can specify the root manually as `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 1}`.

If you *know* you have a directed tree, you can identify the root as `Pick[VertexList[g], VertexInDegree[g], 0]`.

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 3}, 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 1}, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

There is also `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`, which is designed for directed acyclic graphs in general, and will select the proper root automatically. However, the plot will look somewhat different:

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 3}, 
  GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

To flip the plot upside down, you can use the `"Orientation" -> Bottom` suboption for either of these two layouts, `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 1,  "Orientation" -> Bottom}`.

---

Alternatively, use the `IGLayoutReingoldTilford` function from my [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/), which selects the root properly, and is otherwise quite similar to `"LayeredEmbedding"`.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
IGLayoutReingoldTilford[g, "Rotation" -> Pi]
```

[image]

It also has the `IGTreeQ` function which can test for *directed* trees, unlike `TreeGraphQ`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Very insightful and much appreciated, Michel.